# keyboard shortcut for latin hook f

Tags: shortcut-keys

Is there a Ubuntu keyboard shortcut to type a "ƒ" ([latin hook f](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C6%91))?

On a Mac, I used to be able to do <kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and it worked everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main ways of doing this, it's genearlly down to personal preference which you choose:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, then <kbd>0</kbd>
   <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

or

2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u0192</kbd>

EDIT: Option 2 will work in most cases, but may not work in some places, including certain terminals.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> is the command sequence for inserting any unicode character, and 0192 is the character code for "LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH HOOK"

Comment: This doesn't work here - I get completely different characters, and need to press <ESC> to get the prompt back.

Comment: Type the numbers one at a time, but keep Ctrl+Shift held down whilst you type them. So push Ctrl+Shift+U, then let go of 'U', and type the number one character at a time.

Comment: Apologies, it looks like the second option only works in certain text areas, will edit to make this clear